# File Not Found, but the file is there!

Tags: c#

```
public static List<Product> Load(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Data could not be found ", filename );
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 gives the following exception, "FileNotFoundException"

emmm.. ok. this problem seem to have been solved.

.

But however, I still can not find the file!! But the file is there, in the same directory, Ive already verified and double-verified the name is correct! I have no idea what is going on.

The file is called "Products.xml".

Comment: The file was not found probably? It's your own exception

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code.  What were you expecting to happen when you failed to find a file specified in the location that `filename` holds?

Comment: Stupid Visual Studio. Always throwing exceptions! ;)

Comment: Please read through the answers. As @DaveRead has answered (and also [linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)),  "if the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false **regardless** of the existence of path."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file is called "Products.xml".

You expose yourself to random failure with a filename like that.  You should use the full path name of the file, like c:\mumble\foo\products.xml.  If you don't then you completely rely on your program's working directory being set correctly.  The value of Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Even if it is set correctly by whatever program is starting yours (like a shortcut on the desktop), you still can get into trouble when code you didn't write changes the working directory.  A good example is OpenFileDialog with the RestoreDirectory property left to the default value of false.

Always use full path names in your code.  Or let the user select the file.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. emm.. now I just created a stream with XML serializer, makes life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2):

You are the one who is throwing the exception. Do you mean to put up an error message?

Comment: yap, I want it to output an error message if the file is not found. That being said, the file is actually there...

Answer (score 2):

File.Exists may return false if the user that the code runs under does not have access to the file, as well as if the does not exist.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is `File.Exists` is returning false and you're throwing an exception which is not handled by your code.  Did you intend for this exception to be handled or does this represent a fatal error to your program?

Answer (score 0):

The file located at `filename`  does not exist, and thus it throws the exception with the following line: `throw new FileNotFoundException("Data could not be found ", filename );`

Did you mean to just output an error?

Comment: yap, I wanted to output an error if the file is not found, is this not the way to do it?

Comment: @Rosie: To show an error to your user you usually just show them a `MessageBox`. You only throw exceptions on fatal conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In you code first check for empty filename as the passed parameter may be empty string, plus apply try catch block on the code as the passed filename might not satisfy the path rules for a file. in catch block through your exception too.

Answer (score 0):

You either:

A) Don't want to throw the exception via this line

> throw new FileNotFoundException()

and instead want to display a Dialog to the user, or use some other error handling technique in there. To output an error either use one of the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("File not found") 
MessageBox.Show("File not found");
```

B) Higher up in your call stack have a try/catch and handle your error there, similarly with a dialog or another error handling approach suitable for your application.

```
try
{
   Load(filename);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
{}
```