# Open html file using relative path

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have an html file I need to open.

I used this code

```
try 
{ 
    Process.Start("HelpPage.htm"); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

as you see I used the relative path to the file.
But it didn't work.
It throws an error:

> THE SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE FILE SPECIFIED

Comment: What exactly was the problem?

Comment: You need to open for reading? what do you want to do?

Comment: Please show us the code? What is the error or problem? do you get an exception?

Comment: THE CODE IS

 try
            {

                Process.Start("HelpPage.htm");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

AND THE ERROR "THE SYSTEM CANOT FINED THE FILE SPECIFIED"

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written, I think the problem is that your path is - as you already know - relative.

```
try{ 
   Process.Start("HelpPage.htm"); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

This code wants to open a file in the same folder your application is running, your ExecuteablePath:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location //This is the application path
```

Now if the file is not existent at that location, it can't be opened.
So following this it's consequential that a [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is thrown.

Now:

If you want to open a file on X:\myFolder\myFolder2\myHTMLfile.html

You have to pass the absolute file path to your application:

You can do this by

```
Process.Start("X:\\myFolder\\myFolder2\\myHTMLfile.html");
```

Here you mask the backslash with a second backslash or

```
Process.Start(@"X:\myFolder\myFolder2\myHTMLfile.html");
```

> The advantage of @-quoting is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write [and read]

For more info look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

EDIT:

If the file is existent in the ApplicationDirectory, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475265/file-not-found-but-the-file-is-there) could help.